# How can I keep track of a changing file?

Tags: files

It will be changing name and content. And eventually inode (after a backup).

Is there a way of keeping a fixed reference ID to a file? At least, if I have a list of inodes, how can I connect it with the new inodes when I backup or transfer the file to a new partition?

Comment: New name, new content, new inode.  But same file ?  Sounds like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus

Comment: @steve. Almost, the content won't change completely. Unhappily even changing a couple of bites will change the md5sum (or similar hash) completely.

Comment: Do you want to do this in a shell script?  or with perl or python or similar?  C?  some other language?  on which OS? (Linux, Mac, *bsd, other?).   If Linux, the kernel's `inotify`API can be used to set watches on files and directories, but it's difficult to say more than that without knowing what programming/scripting language you intend to use.   search the reference documentation for the language for `inotify`.   See also the [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/) for the `inotifywatch` and `inotifywait` tools which can be used from shell.

Comment: please edit your question and add more details about OS & language, exactly what you're trying to do, how you intend to do it, what you've tried so far (and what happened).

Comment: [The question is:](http://xyproblem.info/) Why? What's the purpose of continuously tracking it? Isn't it enough, at any given time when you need access to the data, to search for it and use what's available and sufficiently matches the criteria for this kind of file/data? Why not?